# Problems regarding conversion of List to Array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

What I want to do:

I want to create an array and add each Item from a List to the array. This is what I have so far:

```
count = 0
arr = []

with open(path,encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
    data = f.readlines() #Data is the List



for s in data:    
    arr[count] = s
    count+=1
```

What am I doing wrong? The Error I get is **IndexError: list assignment index out of range**

Comment: `arr.append(s)`..

Comment: Terminology nitpick: there are no arrays in your code. `arr` is a list. So really you're asking "how do I convert a list to a list?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `arr` is an empty array. So, `arr[count] = s` is giving that error.

Either you initialize your array with empty elements, or use the `append` method of array. Since you do not know how many elements you will be entering into the array, it is better to use the `append` method in this case.

```
for s in data:    
    arr.append(s)
    count+=1
```

Answer (score 4):

When you try to access `arr` at index `0`, there is not anything there. What you are trying to do is add to it. You should do `arr.append(s)`

Answer (score 1):

It's worth taking a step back and asking what you're trying to do here.

`f` is already an iterable of lines: something you can loop over with `for line in f:`. But it's "lazy"—once you loop over it once, it's gone. And it's not a sequence—you can loop over it, but you can't randomly access it with indexes or slices like `f[20]` or `f[-10:]`.

`f.readlines()` copies that into a list of lines: something you can loop over, and index. While files have the `readlines` method for this, it isn't really necessary—you can convert *any* iterable to a list just like this by just calling `list(f)`.

Your loop appears to be an attempt to create another list of the same lines. Which you could do with just `list(data)`. Although it's not clear why you need another list in the first place.

---

Also, the term "array" betrays some possible confusion.

A Python list is a dynamic array, which can be indexed and modified, but can also be resized by appending, inserting, and deleting elements. So, technically, `arr` is an array.

But usually when people talk about "arrays" in Python, they mean fixed-size arrays, usually of fixed-size objects, like those provided by the stdlib `array` module, the third-party `numpy` library, or special-purpose types like the builtin `bytearray`.

In general, to convert a list or other iterable into any of these is the same as converting into a list: just call the constructor. For example, if you have a list of numbers between 0-255, you can do `bytearray(lst)` to get a bytearray of the same numbers. Or, if you have a list of lists of float values, `np.array(lst)` will give you a 2D numpy array of floats. And so on.

---

So, why doesn't your code work?

When you write `arr = []`, you're creating a list of 0 elements.

When you write `arr[count] = s`, you're trying to set the `count`th element in the list to `s`. But there *is* no `count`th element. You're writing past the end of the list.

One option is to call `arr.append(s)` instead. This makes the list 1 element longer than it used to be, and puts `s` in the new slot.

Another option is to create a list of the right size in the first place, like `arr = [None for _ in data]`. Then, `arr[count] = s` can replace the `None` in the `count`th slot with `s`.

But if you really just want a copy of `data` in another list, you're better off just using `arr = list(data)`, or `arr = data[:]`.

And if you don't have any need for another copy, just do `arr = data`, or just use `data` as-is—or even, if it works for your needs, just use `f` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are coming from matlab or R background. when you do `arr=[]`, it creates an empty list, its not an array.

```
import numpy
count = 0   
with open(path,encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
    data = f.readlines() #Data is the List

size = len(data)
array = numpy.zeros((size,1))

for s in data:    
    arr[count,0] = s
    count+=1
```